# How can I convert a JSON date with timezone to a SQL Server datetime?

Tags: sql-server, json, datetime

I saved the output of a JSON object in a CSV file. I want to import the data into SQL Server. I have tried to cast the JSON date column to a SQL Server datetime data type.

```
select cast('2009-06-18T16:44:20+0000' as datetime)
```

This causes an error to be raised: Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string.

How can I convert a JSON date with timezone to a SQL Server datetime?

Comment: Use the datetimeoffset data type?

Comment: I already tried the datatimeoffset but it didn't work. There is something funky about the JSON dates.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As far as I know, SQL Server recognizes timezone with colon. You have to reformat timezone part as follows:

```
SELECT CONVERT(datetime2, STUFF('2009-06-18T16:44:20+0000', 23, 0, ':'))
```

According to [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb630289.aspx) ISO 8601 has `YYYY-MM-DDThh:mm:ss[.nnnnnnn][{+|-}hh:mm]` format.

Answer (score 5):

I had a similar issue; I was getting the same error though the date format for my dates are a little different. The solution for me was to convert it to a DATETIME2 value, instead of just DATETIME. Had I not seen Pawel's answer, I would not have tried converting to DATETIME2.

The dates that I was getting were from a C# object that was serialized to JSON using JSON.Net. Below is a sample SQL script showing what the datetime values were and how to convert it.

```
DECLARE @effectiveDateJSON VARCHAR(MAX) = 
'{"EffectiveDate":"2017-02-07T00:00:00-06:00", "CreateDate":"2017-02-07T16:32:12.9130892-06:00"}';

SELECT *
FROM OPENJSON(@effectiveDateJSON)
WITH (EffectiveDate DATETIME2 '$.EffectiveDate',
    CreateDate DATETIME2 '$.CreateDate'
);
```

Comment: This is a much better solution than the "approved" one.

Comment: @oleg no its not. It assumes a time format other than the original question. The original question has no colon in timezone. This answer asumes it does. If the original poster has no control over the json output this answer is useless and the accepted one much better.

Answer (score 0):

For a timezone aware conversion

```sql
declare @offset datetimeoffset = JSON_VALUE('{"d": "2021-01-01T00:00:00+03:00"}', '$.d')

declare @inCurrentTimezone datetime = @offset AT TIME ZONE CURRENT_TIMEZONE_ID()

select @inCurrentTimezone
```

Docs:[AT TIME ZONE](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/at-time-zone-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15), [datetimeoffset](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/datetimeoffset-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15#time-zone-offset)