# Extract Date in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a date format as : `2015-07-11T16:35:02`.

I want only the date from the mentioned datetime.ie.(2015-07-11).

How would I convert the date.

Comment: Column data type?

Comment: Column datatype is Varchar

Comment: Don't store date/time values in varchar columns. Use proper data types!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I convert a JSON date with timezone to a SQL Server datetime?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38982977/how-can-i-convert-a-json-date-with-timezone-to-a-sql-server-datetime)

Answer (score 3):

```
Use convert to get result :

SELECT CONVERT(DATE,'2015-07-11T16:35:02',102)

For Comparison use below format :

IF CAST('2015-07-11T16:35:02' AS DATETIME) >= CAST('2015-07-11T16:35:02' AS 
    DATETIME)     

     SELECT CAST('2015-07-11T16:35:02' AS DATETIME)
```

Comment: i have to compare two columns and both of them in varchar. column B format is 2015-07-11T16:35:02 and column A format is 2015-07-11 16:35:02,where column B has to be > column A.can you help??

Answer (score 0):

You can use `CONVERT` :

```
SELECT CONVERT(DATE, '2015-07-11T16:35:02')
```

This will result in : `2015-07-11`

For the column, you can use :

```
SELECT CONVERT(DATE, INSERT_DATE)
```

Hope this helps!!!

Comment: i have to compare two columns and both of them in varchar. column B format is 2015-07-11T16:35:02 and column A format is 2015-07-11 16:35:02,where column B has to be > column A.can you help??

Answer (score 0):

Do this. Just done Casting it to date datatype.

```
SELECT CAST('2015-07-11T16:35:02' AS DATE)
```

The result will be `2015-07-11`

Comment: i have to compare two columns .

Comment: Which colomns you want to compare?

Comment: i have to compare two columns and both of them in varchar. column B format is 2015-07-11T16:35:02 and column A format is 2015-07-11 16:35:02,where column B has to be > column A.can you help??

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), '2015-07-11T16:35:02')
```

Checkout this link for more info: [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx)

Comment: i have to compare two columns and both of them in varchar. column B format is 2015-07-11T16:35:02 and column A format is 2015-07-11 16:35:02,where column B has to be > column A.can you help??

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT CONVERT(varchar(10), INSERT_DATE,102)
```

Comment: i have to compare two columns and both of them in varchar. column B format is 2015-07-11T16:35:02 and column A format is 2015-07-11 16:35:02,where column B has to be > column A.can you help??

Comment: @JacksonVJose Add some explanation as well.

Comment: `Select * from tblName where convert(datetime,ColumB)>convert(datetime,ColumA)`